# Oracle sql to pgsql with table() function issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I am doing the migration from Oracle to pgsql and I've the the oracle sql like below:

```
select code,product_no,qty qty from t_ma_tb_inventory 
                    where code is not null and status=2
                    and update_type in (select * from table(splitstr(:types,',')))
                    and tb_shop_id=:shopId 
                     order by update_time
```

and the splitstr function like below:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION splitstr (p_string text, p_delimiter text) RETURNS SETOF STR_SPLIT AS $body$
    DECLARE

        v_length   bigint := LENGTH(p_string);
        v_start    bigint := 1;
        v_index    bigint;

    BEGIN
        WHILE(v_start <= v_length)
        LOOP
            v_index := INSTR(p_string, p_delimiter, v_start);

            IF v_index = 0
            THEN
                RETURN NEXT SUBSTR(p_string, v_start);
                v_start := v_length + 1;
            ELSE
                RETURN NEXT SUBSTR(p_string, v_start, v_index - v_start);
                v_start := v_index + 1;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN;
    END
    $body$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    SECURITY DEFINER
    ;

-- REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION splitstr (p_string text, p_delimiter text) FROM PUBLIC;
```

can someone help me to write the equivalent code in pgsql?Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write your own function - Postgres already has a built-in function for that: `string_to_array`

```
select code, product_no, qty qty 
from t_ma_tb_inventory 
where code is not null and status=2
  and update_type = any ( string_to_array(:types,',') )
  and tb_shop_id = :shopId 
order by update_time;
```

If you are passing a text, but you need to compare that to an integer, you need to cast the resulting array:

```
select code, product_no, qty qty 
from t_ma_tb_inventory 
where code is not null and status=2
  and update_type = any ( string_to_array(:types,',')::int[] )
  and tb_shop_id = :shopId 
order by update_time;
```

---

However: that is a pretty ugly workaround that is only necessary in Oracle because it has no support for real arrays in SQL (only in PL/SQL).

In Postgres it would be **much** better to pass an array of integers directly (e.g. make `:types` an `int[]`). Then no parsing or casting would be necessary:

```
select code, product_no, qty qty 
from t_ma_tb_inventory 
where code is not null and status=2
  and update_type = any ( :types )
  and tb_shop_id = :shopId 
order by update_time;
```

Comment: thanks,and what about the :types argument is the int?what shall i do?Sorry,I am new to pgsql

Comment: You have not shown how you run that statement. But I assumed the parameter `:types` that you use there is a `text` value (because your function also expects `text` there). How and where are you replacing those parameters? What was the data type of `:types` in Oracle?

Comment: @CarlosZhang: see my edit. In Postgres you don't actually need all that if you simply pass an `int[]` directly